# How can I display only part of an email address using jquery?

Tags: jquery, email

I have a requirement to only display the first section of the email address. For example I have myemail@mydomain.com and I only want to display "myemail" on my webpage. I have no experience with regexp. Thanks.

Comment: You can split a string using javascript without a regex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Hiding the @mydomain.com part with javascript will not stop spiders from getting the email addresses, fyi. Doing it with server-side code would work, and the required regex and/or string manipulation would be very similar.

Comment: seems like a perfect time to learn regex eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string on the @

```
email.split("@")[0]
```

Hum, maybe you need to know how to get emails too :

```
mails = $('a[href^="mailto"]');
mails.each(function() {
    $(this).text(this.text.split('@')[0] + "@...")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Javascript:

```
var email = "myemail@mydomain.com";
alert(email.substr(0, email.indexOf("@")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses I ended up doing the .Split('@') server-side